# VBA If statement confusion

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba

The below code worked fine until I added the code for the `vbokcancel` bit... code below:

```
If Me.results.ListIndex = -1 Or Me.userfolder.ListIndex = -1 Or
Me.choice.ListIndex = -1 Then           

MsgBox "Please choose something to remove"

Else

If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this user from this folder?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then

    If Me.choice.Value = "Folder" Then

        username = Me.results.Column(0)
        prfolder = Me.results.Column(3)

        strSQL = "DELETE tblRelationship.*, tblPra.praNo, tblFolder.folder FROM tblPra INNER JOIN (tblFolder INNER JOIN tblRelationship ON tblFolder.folderID = tblRelationship.folderID) ON tblPra.praID = tblRelationship.praID WHERE (((tblPra.praNo)='" & username & "') AND ((tblFolder.folder)='" & prfolder & "'));"
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
        Me.results.Requery

    ElseIf Me.choice.Value = "Username" Then

        prfolder = Me.results.Column(0)

        strSQL = "DELETE tblRelationship.*, tblFolder.folder FROM tblPra INNER JOIN (tblFolder INNER JOIN tblRelationship ON tblFolder.folderID = tblRelationship.folderID) ON tblPra.praID = tblRelationship.praID WHERE (((tblFolder.folder)='" & prfolder & "'));"
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
        Me.results.Requery

    End If
  End If
End If
```

It will activate the `If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this user from this folder?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK` section but if the "OK" button is clicked it skips straight to the `End If` and does not run the code within the IF statement. Now I thought what I did was perfectly "Legal" in coding, apparently not... any ideas what I've done to screw up?

If you press "Cancel" it does what I already want it to do, which is close the message box and the user is back at the same screen.. so there's no need for an Else statement because it already does what I want it to do.

Comment: The `If MsgBox` part looks ok. Are you sure it isn't the `If Me.choice.Value = .. ` lines that don't work? Add a line `MsgBox "Clicked OK"` directly after the question.

Comment: Hi, I added that and it still skips to the second `End If` without showing "Clicked Ok"

Comment: Hmm. Is this your original code, or did you change anything when you posted the question? Try this in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G): `If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this user from this folder?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then MsgBox "Clicked OK"` -- it should show the 2nd MsgBox if you click OK.

Comment: @Andre If I change it to this: `If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this user from this folder?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
    
            MsgBox "User will not be deleted"
            
        Else`   It seems to work... But I will also try your method to.

Comment: @Andre That still didn't work, but I have found a way around it so it does work, it's not ideal but will have to do I guess. I Don't think it likes not having an `else` statement.

Comment: It sounds silly, but try assigned the results of the message box to a variable first, then checking that variable in the `IF` statement.

Comment: @MichaelRusso That does the same thing, and just jumps to the `End If` to!

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints in the debugger?

Comment: Yep, that's how I know it jumps straight to the End If. I'll just have to use the way I found earlier on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment and it's not really an answer, but it should guide you in the right direction.

Try setting the value of the messagebox equal to a variable.  Something like this:

```
If Me.results.ListIndex = -1 Or Me.userfolder.ListIndex = -1 Or
Me.choice.ListIndex = -1 Then           

MsgBox "Please choose something to remove"

Else

    X = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this user from this folder?", vbOKCancel)

    If X = vbOK Then  'put a breakpoint here

        If Me.choice.Value = "Folder" Then

            username = Me.results.Column(0)
            prfolder = Me.results.Column(3)

            strSQL = "DELETE tblRelationship.*, tblPra.praNo, tblFolder.folder FROM tblPra INNER JOIN (tblFolder INNER JOIN tblRelationship ON tblFolder.folderID = tblRelationship.folderID) ON tblPra.praID = tblRelationship.praID WHERE (((tblPra.praNo)='" & username & "') AND ((tblFolder.folder)='" & prfolder & "'));"
            CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
            Me.results.Requery

        ElseIf Me.choice.Value = "Username" Then

            prfolder = Me.results.Column(0)

            strSQL = "DELETE tblRelationship.*, tblFolder.folder FROM tblPra INNER JOIN (tblFolder INNER JOIN tblRelationship ON tblFolder.folderID = tblRelationship.folderID) ON tblPra.praID = tblRelationship.praID WHERE (((tblFolder.folder)='" & prfolder & "'));"
            CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
            Me.results.Requery

        End If
    End If

End If
```

Then, check X's value and see what it thinks X is equal to.  That should give you an idea of why the If/Then code block isn't working.

Comment: It thinks that X is equal to 1, which sadly doesn't explain (to me anyway) why it skips to the end if!

Comment: Did you try changing **If X = vbOK** to **If X = 1**?  Or, in your original code, change **If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this user from this folder?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK** to **If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this user from this folder?", vbOKCancel) = 1** and see if it acts as desired.  However, I'd first check the values of both OK and Cancel to see what X thinks they are, then change your original (or my version) appropriately.

Comment: Ok changing `If X = vbOK Then` to `If X = 1 Then` has finally done it the way I want it to do it. Thank you very much! It's seems so obvious now..

Comment: Not so obvious, because it SHOULD recognize vbOK.  I have no idea why it's not.  But happy to have found a work-around.